# Android/ Java : IS there fast way to filter large data saved in a list ? and how to get high quality picture with small storage space in server?

Tags: list, image, filter, storage, textwatcher

I have two questions
the first one is:
I have large data come from the server I saved it in a list , the customer can filter this data by 7 filters and two by text watcher this thing caused filtering operation to slow it takes 4 seconds in each time 
I tried to put the filter keywords like(length or width ...) in one if and (&&) between them
but it didn't give me a result, also I tried to replace the textwatcher by spinner but it's not 
useful. 
I'm using one (for loop)

**So the question: how can I use multi filter for list contain up to 2000 row with mini or zero slow?**

the second is:
I saved from 2 to 8 pictures in the server in string form
the question is when I get these pictures from the server how can I show them in high quality?
when I show them I can see the pixels and this is not good for the customer 
**I don't want these pictures to take large space in the server and at the same time I want it in good quality when I restore them to display**

I'm using Android/ Java
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide code examples of what you have tried, and read the advice on [ask] and how to provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The answer on my first quistion is if you want using filter (like when you are using online clothes shop and you want to filter it by less price ) you should use the hash map, not ordinary list it will be faster

The answer on my second question is: if you want to save store images in a database you should save it as a link, not a string or any other datatype